# C# - polling a device by TCP/IP

Tags: c#, optimization, tcp, modbus

I tried to poll the device using the Modbus protocol for TCP/IP, and it works well, but there are problems.

If I run this code on a weak computer, the response time will increase and very much...
The difference in polling speed is about 6 seconds.

For example - I send a request on my computer `01 03 04 50 00 01 85 2B` and received a response in `0.057` seconds, and on a weaker computer this request is received in `0.560` seconds. The answer is the same `01 03 02 02 C1 78 B4`. The device is the same and connected in the same way.

```
public override void Run()
    {
        IsRunning = true;
        OnJobStarted?.Invoke(this);
        OnLogMessage?.Invoke(this, "JOB START");
        try
        {
            while (Job.ThreadState == ThreadState.Running && !isJobTerminated)
            {
                var ts = DateTime.Now;
                if (!Ping())
                {

                }
                var es = DateTime.Now;
                var ms = (es - ts).TotalMilliseconds;
                while (!isJobTerminated && (DateTime.Now - ts).TotalMilliseconds <= this.PingInterval * 1000)
                    Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            OnLogMessage?.Invoke(this, " RUN: " + ex.Message);
        }
        OnLogMessage?.Invoke(this, "JOB END");
        OnJobEnded?.Invoke(this);
        IsRunning = false;
    }
```

.

```
public override bool Ping()
    {
        var result = false;
        try
        {
            PingStat.LastPingDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            PingStat.PingInterval = this.PingInterval;

            result = true;
            PingStat.TotalPingCount++;
            if (!result)
                PingStat.ErrorCount++;

            if (result)
            {
                foreach (var md in Children.Where(m => !m.IsSuspended && m.IsEnabled))
                {
                    var pingResult = ReadConfiguration(md).ErrorCode == 0;
                    Thread.Sleep(10);

                    if (pingResult)
                        ReadState(md);
                    if (pingResult && md.IsMaskChanged)
                    {
                        var maskResult = WriteSingleRegister(md, 0x05FC, md.Mask);
                        md.IsMaskChanged = !(maskResult.ErrorCode == 0);
                    }

                    md.PingStat.IsLastPingOk = pingResult;
                    md.OnPing?.Invoke(md, pingResult);

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            OnLogMessage?.Invoke(this, ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace);
            result = false;
        }
        finally
        {
            PingStat.IsLastPingOk = result;
            OnPing?.Invoke(this, result);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

.

```
public override RcResult ExecuteModBus(RcModBusDevice device, byte[] request, out byte[] answer)
    {
        answer = null;
        var result = new RcResult();
        var dt = DateTime.Now;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        try
        {
            OnLogMessage?.Invoke(this, "ExecuteModBus Lock?");
            lock (communication)
            {

                OnLogMessage?.Invoke(this, "ExecuteModBus Lock!");

                using (var tcpClient = new TcpClient())
                {
                    tcpClient.Connect(IP, Port);
                    tcpClient.SendTimeout = SendTimeout;
                    tcpClient.ReceiveTimeout = Math.Max(100, ReceiveTimeout);
                    using (var stream = tcpClient.GetStream())
                    {
                        dt = DateTime.Now;
                        OnLogMessage?.Invoke(this, "REQUEST->:" + Utils.BytesToHex(request));
                        stream.Write(request, 0, request.Length);

                        var tmp = new byte[0xA0];
                        int dataLength = 0;

                        try
                        {

                            for (dataLength = 0; dataLength < tmp.Length; dataLength++)
                            {
                                tmp[dataLength] = (byte)(stream.ReadByte());
                                tcpClient.ReceiveTimeout = 100 - Properties.Settings.Default.coefIP;
                                Thread.Sleep(0);
                            }

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                        }

                        if (dataLength < 2)
                            result.ErrorCode = 1;
                        else
                        {
                            var crc = Utils.GetCRC(tmp, 0, dataLength - 2);
                            if (crc[0] != tmp[dataLength - 2] || crc[1] != tmp[dataLength - 1])
                            {
                                result.ErrorCode = 1;
                                result.ErrorText = "Bad CRC";
                            }
                        }
                        answer = new byte[dataLength];
                        Array.Copy(tmp, 0, answer, 0, dataLength);
                    }
                    OnLogMessage?.Invoke(this, "ANSWER<-:" + Utils.BytesToHex(answer));
                    if (device != null)
                        SaveToLog(DbID, device.DbID, dt, Utils.BytesToHex(request), DateTime.Now, Utils.BytesToHex(answer));
                }
            }
            OnLogMessage?.Invoke(this, "ExecuteModBus UnLock");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SaveToLog(DbID, device.DbID, dt, Utils.BytesToHex(request), DateTime.Now, "ERROR", ex.Message);
            OnLogMessage?.Invoke(this, ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace);
            result = new RcResult() { ErrorCode = 1, ErrorText = ex.Message };
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: In a question about latency and integration testing, how useful is it to have `Sleep` in your code?

Comment: @MickyD The question is why this happens. As for the waiting time, they weren’t at the beginning, I was just trying to figure out where the time was leaking. They do not affect performance.

Comment: FYI:  Thread.Sleep(10) guarantees a MINIMUM of 10ms sleep time.   It could be more!  After 10ms the system may still prioritise/process other threads before it wakes the thread.  So on a slower CPU then this make also take longer as the processing of other tasks takes longer too.

Comment: Difference between 0.057 and 0.560 is 0.503 second, not 6 seconds.

Comment: I think difference is the connection speed and not the c# code.  Try from cmd.exe >Ping and see what response speed is.

Comment: So reading the bytes one by one with Sleep () is a bad design, with the Modbus TCP protocol you can know exactly how many bytes you are going to receive and you should use `Read (byte [] buffer, int offset, int size)` instead `ReadByte ()`. Also in protocols that send responses of variable length, the total byte length is always received at the beginning, then just the first bytes are read to know the length and then the rest is read.